# What's another term for "team of employees"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, terminology

What's a term other than "team" for a group of employees who work well together?

Comment: What did the thesaurus say for team that you didn't like?

Comment: Thesauri often don't really give enough of a sense of ... the baggage(?) a word carries, and often it takes quite some time to look up every supposed synonym in a dictionary. They also tend to be quite out-of-date in terms of what's currently idiomatic. That said, yes, *some* evidence of research *would* be nice :)

Answer (score 2):

While there could be many answers to your question, the way "**squad**" is often used would work.  It does have some sorts of military and police connotations making it a better name for a "team that takes on a problem" or a bit more crisis driven.

In it's common use it frequently suggests something of a tight knit group trained to a specific purpose.

... also in an informal way, as suggested by the more recently evolved slang definition for a group of friends, I believe the term implies a bond of cooperation ... perhaps evolved from the military 'brothers in arms', perhaps the interdependence most squads require.  It means more than a subsegment or classification group.

> [**squad** at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/squad)
>
> 1.
>   a small number of soldiers, commonly 10 privates, a staff sergeant, and a corporal; the smallest military unit.
>
> 2.
>   a group of police officers, especially one organized to deal with a particular area of law enforcement:
>   drug squad; fraud squad.
>
> 3.
>   any small group or party of persons engaged in a common enterprise.
>
> 4.
>   a sports team or a group of players from which a team is selected.
>
> 5.
>   Slang. a group of friends.

Other military designations are frequently used in a similar way

- "Brigade" - while a large group in a miltary sense has a common conotation of "get to work on what needs to be done" in my opinion
- "Force"  As in police force - yet I think it has more of super-hero taste to it too.

Comment: Nothing here answers the *work well together* part of the question (which seems important).

Comment: @WillCrawford  I do think the designation 'squad' implies a large degree of cohesiveness and experience in working closely together.  A 'group' might go either way.  A scientific study would have focus groups, placebo groups, etc.. but a 'placebo squad' would be nonsensical precisely because the term squad means more than a subset .  I'd say that 'squad' goes beyond team in it's connotations of close cooperation if I had to pick one or the other...but both imply more than a group or classfication

Comment: The definitions you quoted don't really say that (unless you consider the "friends" slang meaning, but that's not in a "working" context). Looking at some other definitions online, though, I'm inclined to agree with you :o) sorry.

Comment: (I can't upvote unless you edit the answer, though)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the word 'crew'.

> a company of people working on one job or under one foreman or operating a machine

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crew)

> Why was there a **film crew** in Old Market Square ?

[Nottingham Post 23rd January 2018](http://www.nottinghampost.com/whats-on/film/film-crew-old-market-square-1104553)

> **Road crew** uncovers tunnel near Mexico border in Texas

[Daily Mail 26th January 2018](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/ap/article-5317705/Road-crew-uncovers-tunnel-near-Mexico-border-Texas.html)

Comment: I understand "crew." What I'm seeking is a term that describes the opposite of "new hire." The newly hired (neophyte) feels solitary and fumbling within the office or company culture. After a while, the newly hired worker feels welcomed and expert within the culture. Also, the chosen word needs to "sound" plain or common. "Adept," "Adroit," and "Skilled" connote manual dexterity and don't include the notion that the others now feel that they can rely on the recent employee. "Team" works, but it seems trite. I have settled on the word "accomplished" for this draft, and I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @MichaelPearl I think that should all have gone into the question.

Comment: Probably so. I'm a newcomer to this site. Please be patient with me as I become more expert in its culture.

Comment: @MichaelPearl No harm done. I've made bigger errors than that and I'm still here.

Comment: @MichaelPearl StackExchange is *very* Q&A focused. They aim to build a repository of on-topic questions and community-assessed answers, and they've implemented this (in part) by making the question and answer sections a lot more permanent than comments. If your question's text doesn't reflect your intent accurately, feel free to edit it so that it does - this is encouraged and will help the community avoid posting answers that relate to the text of your question but not to what you're really trying to ask. The edit link can be found just below your question.

Answer (score 0):

A better term that includes more of the “as opposed to new hire” part of your meaning is ***[cadre](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cadre)*** (Online Etymology Dictionary), especially:

> "permanently organized framework of a military unit" (the officers, etc., **as opposed to the rank-and-file**), 1851

[emphasis mine].

Although that's referring to their *status*, the general meaning is (as noted in that entry) derived from the French meaning "frame", implying strength and support and so on.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for considering my question. I was struggling to find a term that would fit both my meaning and my audience. I also looked at "enculturated" and "assimilated;" instead, I settled on "accomplished." Here is the context: (See next comment)

Comment: Context: Through daily contact with the company, its operations, supervisors, and fellow employees, the “new hire” repeatedly encounters the culture of the company and becomes an “accomplished” member of the company. The person who does not integrate is soon out of a job.

Comment: I'm not convinced - *accomplished* doesn't really imply *integrated*, although it certainly denotes successes. *Assimilated*, while it might sound weird to you now, is the “right” word for it :o)

Answer (score 0):

If your focus is *entirely* on the “work well together” part, then there are a number of idioms: the most reliable (though in danger of being a *cliché*) is *[like] **a well-oiled machine***; the rest you can probably find by feeding that phrase into a Google search and aimlessly clicking around.